# Unlink p4 client from a changelist and delete the client

Tags: version-control, perforce, changelist

I have opened a p4 client and associated it with an already created changelist. That changelist(not created by me) is in pending status. That changelist is associated with changes done by someone else. I want to delete my p4 client. I have reverted the changes done by me using "p4 revert file-name". "p4 opened" is showing nothing. I'm not allowed to delete the changelist using "p4 change -d change-number" as it contains changes by others. In this scenario, I'm executing "p4 client -d client-name" to delete my p4 client. But, it's throwing error as it's associated with a pending changelist. How to delete my p4 client without deleting the pending changelist? I'm expecting that I have to unlink my p4 client from the changelist and then I have to delete it. How to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same way you claimed ownership of this change in the first place -- run "p4 change change-number" and edit the Client field to point at someone else's client.

Comment: In this way, if I try to associate my p4 client to an already committed changelist, it shows error as **"Can't update committed change change-num"**. It only works if I re-associate my p4 client to another pending changelist which I can delete. Then I can delete my p4 client as it's not associated with any pending changelist anymore.